# One word for person you meet by chance

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for a person you meet specifically by chance.  Ideally, a single word for someone you have never met before, but words for acquaintances would also be great.

An example sentence might be

> They waved goodbye to their amusing [person-word-here] and continued on their walk through the park.

Comment: As to why the SWR restriction: I am writing a short dialogue and am referring to the chance-met encounter by a different adjective and noun each time, depending on what they say.  I knew what adjective I wanted to use, but couldn't find the right word for the noun...

Answer (score 1):

“I waved goodbye to my amusing encounter”. This is a shift in the meaning of “encounter” but seems acceptable.